# How to parse multiline string

Tags: python

I have a requirement to execute command `ps -T --pid <pid> -o comm,class,pri` which I am executing using `subprocess` like below:

```
cmd = 'ps -T --pid ' + pid + ' -o comm,class,pri'
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    
out, err = proc.communicate()
output_str = out.decode('latin-1')
print(output_str)
```

It produces output in below string format:

```
COMMAND  CLS PRI
A        FF  139
B        FF   41
C        FF  139
```

I want to parse above and store each value of every line in separate variables. How to do it in Python?

Comment: What is the actual final data structure which you want here?

Comment: I want to validate here - for COMMAND B, whether CLS is FF or not.

Comment: You could use a dictionary to store CLS and PRI data for each COMMAND

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the format of the data you could do something like this:

```
output_dict = {}
for line in output_str:
    if line.startswith("COMMAND"): continue
    command_list = line.split(" ")
    output_dict[command_list[0].strip()] = {"CLS": command_list[1].strip(),
                                            "PRI": command_list[2].strip()}
print(output_dict["B"])
```